# Extend the code for more variables (at least 100)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, vector, iteration, array

I have this code (not in best shape) for a problem in 3 variables. It does the job. The problem is I want to extend this to more number of variables around 100 at least. It is very painful to extend this way. I do not know how to extend it. Can some one please help me. I have a very little experience in Mathematica.

```
    f1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := (x1)^2 (x2) - 1
    f2[x1_, x2_, x3_] := (x2)^2 (x3) - 1
    f3[x1_, x2_, x3_] := (x3)^2 (x1) - 1
    f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := {f1[x1, x2, x3], f2[x1, x2, x3], f3[x1, x2, x3]}

    g1[x1_, x2_, x3_] := 1/Sqrt[x2]
    g2[x1_, x2_, x3_] := 1/Sqrt[x3]
    g3[x1_, x2_, x3_] := 1/Sqrt[x1]
    g[x1_, x2_, x3_] := {g1[x1, x2, x3], g2[x1, x2, x3], g3[x1, x2, x3]}

    jac[ {x1, x2, x3}] = {D[g1[x1, x2, x3], {{x1, x2, x3}}], 
      D[g2[x1, x2, x3], {{x1, x2, x3}}], D[g3[x1, x2, x3], {{x1, x2, x3}}]}

    {t1, t2, t3} = {11/10, 11/10, 11/10};
    eps = 10^-1600;
    max = 15;

    a = 1;
    b = SetAccuracy[Norm[f[t1, t2, t3], Infinity], 240];
    k = 1;
    While[k <= max && a + b > eps,
      M = SetAccuracy[- jac[ {x1, x2, x3}] /. {x1 -> t1, x2 -> t2, 
          x3 -> t3}, 240960];
      J = SetAccuracy[
        Inverse[IdentityMatrix[3] - jac[ {x1, x2, x3}] /. {x1 -> t1, 
           x2 -> t2, x3 -> t3}], 240960];
      {z1, z2, z3} = 
       SetAccuracy[J . M . {t1, t2, t3} + J . g[t1, t2, t3], 240];
      {y1, y2, y3} = SetAccuracy[g[z1, z2, z3], 240];
      {h1, h2, h3} = SetAccuracy[g[y1, y2, y3], 240];
      a = SetAccuracy[Norm[({t1, t2, t3} - {h1, h2, h3}), Infinity], 
        240960];
      b = SetAccuracy[Norm[f[h1, h2, h3], Infinity], 240960];
      {t1, t2, t3} = {h1, h2, h3};
      Print["k=", NumberForm[k, 20]];
      Print["{h1,h2,h3}=", NumberForm[{h1, h2, h3}, 20]];
      Print["a=", NumberForm[a, 20]];
      Print["b=", NumberForm[b, 20]];
      k = k + 1;];
    Print["The number of iterations is:" NumberForm[(k - 1), 2]];
    Print["a+b=" NumberForm[a + b, 20]];
```

Comment: I notice `{t1, t2, t3} = {11/10, 11/10, 11/10}`. Will the list of `tn`s always be a constant list, or can individual `tn`s have different values?

Comment: The tn may or may not be always constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd try to generalize, but I'm a bit worried I might have changed your semantics slightly. Since I don't know your context, I can't test very well. There is probably a clever way to do this more "functionally", maybe with `NestWhile`, but I didn't try to reverse engineer your code enough to figure that out.

```
newF[xs_List] := (#[[1]]^2 #[[2]] - 1) & /@ Partition[xs, 2, 1, {1, 1}];
newG[xs_List] := RotateLeft[1/Sqrt[xs]];
newJac[xs : {Symbol__}] := D[#, {xs}] & /@ newG[xs];

Module[
  {eps = 10^-1600,
   max = 15,
   dimensions = 4,
   a, b, k, ts, xs, x},
  ts = N[ConstantArray[11/10, dimensions], 200000];(*set accuracy here*)
  xs = Array[x, dimensions];
  a = 1;
  b = Norm[newF[ts], Infinity];
  k = 1;
  While[
    k <= max && a + b > eps,
    M = -newJac[xs] /. Thread[xs -> ts];
    J = Inverse[IdentityMatrix[dimensions] - newJac[xs] /. Thread[xs -> ts]];
    hs = newG[newG[J . M . ts + J . newG[ts]]];
    a = Norm[(ts - hs), Infinity];
    b = Norm[newF[hs], Infinity];
    Print["k=", NumberForm[k, 20]];
    Print["hs=", NumberForm[hs, 20]];
    Print["a=", NumberForm[a, 20]];
    Print["b=", NumberForm[b, 20]];
    ts = hs;
    k = k + 1];
  Print["The number of iterations is:" NumberForm[(k - 1), 2]];
  Print["a+b=" NumberForm[a + b, 20]]]
```

Comment: I want whole setup to extend to more variables and correspondingly for more functions. I was trying to use for loop but could not able to use that

Comment: Right, but before I go down the road of figuring out your whole setup, I wanted to see if I understood how you want to generalize. So, does my generalization of your first function, `f`, do what you want for more that three arguments?

Comment: Yes, it does work and thank you for that

Comment: Okay, did a bit more generalization, but unfortunately I'll be offline for the rest of the day. Probably shouldn't have gotten started. Maybe this will be enough to get you started, or maybe someone else can help with the rest.

Comment: thank you for your help so far

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. It works now the way I wanted.