# Generalize the code to more variables

Tags: vector, pure-function, finite-difference-method, packed-arrays

I have this code it runs and gives me the solution. How can I make it more compact and If I want it to extend(generalize) it to more variables how can I do it. I had asked a similar question here
([Extend the code for more variables (at least 100)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290289/extend-the-code-for-more-variables-at-least-100))
but I am unable to apply that to these equations. The first problem is to create equations for any arbitrary variable. I want to extend this to around 50 variables I can type the equations but I am assuming that there will be a better way to generalize. Any help is highly appreciated.

It has $x0=0$ and $x10=1$ and 9 unknowns.

```
    f1[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x1) - 
      100/201 ((x2) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x2))^2])
    f2[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x2) - 
      100/201 ((x1) + (x3) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x3) - 5 (x1))^2])
    f3[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x3) - 
      100/201 ((x2) + (x4) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x4) - 5 (x2))^2])
    f4[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x4) - 
      100/201 ((x3) + (x5) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x5) - 5 (x3))^2])
    f5[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x5) - 
      100/201 ((x4) + (x6) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x6) - 5 (x4))^2])
    f6[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x6) - 
      100/201 ((x5) + (x7) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x7) - 5 (x5))^2])
    f7[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x7) - 
      100/201 ((x6) + (x8) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x8) - 5 (x6))^2])
    f8[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x8) - 
      100/201 ((x7) + (x9) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x9) - 5 (x7))^2])
    f9[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := (x9) - 
      100/201 ((x8) + 1 - 1/100 Cos[(5 - 5 (x8))^2])

    f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, 
      x9_] := {f1[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f2[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f3[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f4[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f5[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f6[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f7[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f8[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      f9[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9]}
    g1[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x2) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x2))^2])
    g2[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x1) + (x3) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x3) - 5 (x1))^2])
    g3[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x2) + (x4) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x4) - 5 (x2))^2])
    g4[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x3) + (x5) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x5) - 5 (x3))^2])
    g5[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x4) + (x6) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x6) - 5 (x4))^2])
    g6[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x5) + (x7) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x7) - 5 (x5))^2])
    g7[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x6) + (x8) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x8) - 5 (x6))^2])
    g8[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x7) + (x9) - 1/100 Cos[(5 (x9) - 5 (x7))^2])
    g9[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_] := 
     100/201 ((x8) + 1 - 1/100 Cos[(5 - 5 (x8))^2])

    g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, 
      x9_] := {g1[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g2[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g3[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g4[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g5[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g6[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g7[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g8[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9], 
      g9[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9]}

    jac[ {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}] = {D[
        g1[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g2[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g3[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g4[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g5[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g6[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g7[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g8[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}], 
       D[g9[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, 
         x9], {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}}]};

    {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9} = {1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 
       1/5, 1/5, 1/5};
    eps = 10^-100;
    max = 10;
    per = 200;

    a = 1;
    b = SetAccuracy[Norm[f[t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9], Infinity],
        per];
    k = 1;
    While[k <= max && a + b > eps,
      M = SetAccuracy[- 
          jac[ {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}] /. {x1 -> t1, 
          x2 -> t2, x3 -> t3, x4 -> t4, x5 -> t5, x6 -> t6, x7 -> t7, 
          x8 -> t8, x9 -> t9}, per];
      J = SetAccuracy[
        Inverse[IdentityMatrix[9] - 
           jac[ {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}] /. {x1 -> t1, 
           x2 -> t2, x3 -> t3, x4 -> t4, x5 -> t5, x6 -> t6, x7 -> t7, 
           x8 -> t8, x9 -> t9}], per];
      {z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, z9} = 
       SetAccuracy[
        J . M . {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9} + 
         J . g[t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9], per];
      {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9} = 
       SetAccuracy[g[z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, z9], per];
      {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9} = 
       SetAccuracy[g[y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9], per];
      a = SetAccuracy[
        Norm[({t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9} - {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, 
            h6, h7, h8, h9}), Infinity], per];
      b = SetAccuracy[
        Norm[f[h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9], Infinity], per];
      {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9} = {h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, 
        h8, h9};
      Print["k=", NumberForm[k, 20]];
      Print["{h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9}=", 
       NumberForm[{h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9}, 20]];
      Print["a=", NumberForm[a, 20]];
      Print["b=", NumberForm[b, 20]];
      k = k + 1;];
    Print["The number of iterations is:" NumberForm[(k - 1), 2]];
    Print["a+b=" NumberForm[a + b, 20]];
```

Comment: You could simplify the variable number of arguments by passing a list rather than individual arguments. i.e., for your first definition f1[parms_] := 
 parms[[1]] - 100/201 (parms[[2]] - 1/100 Cos[(5*parms[[2]])^2]); f1[{1, 2, 3}]. You pass the list but the function only uses what it needs.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `f` and `g` to take a list of variables

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[vars_] := Module[{t1, t2}, Table[
   If[n == 1, t1 = 0, t1 = vars[[n - 1]]];
   If[n == Length[vars], t2 = 1, t2 = vars[[n + 1]]];
   vars[[n]] - 100/201 (t1 + t2 - 1/100 Cos[(5 t2 - 5 t1)^2])
   , {n, Length[vars]}]
  ]

g[vars_] := Module[{t1, t2}, Table[
   If[n == 1, t1 = 0, t1 = vars[[n - 1]]];
   If[n == Length[vars], t2 = 1, t2 = vars[[n + 1]]];
   100/201 (t1 + t2 - 1/100 Cos[(5 t2 - 5 t1)^2])
   , {n, Length[vars]}]
  ]

eps = 10^-100;
max = 10;
per = 200;
a = 1;

vars = Array[x, 9];
varst = Table[1/5, {Length[vars]}];
r = Table[vars[[n]] -> varst[[n]], {n, Length[vars]}];
jac2 = Table[D[gg, {vars}], {gg, g[vars]}];
k = 1;
b = SetAccuracy[Norm[f[varst], Infinity], per]

While[k <= max && a + b > eps,
  M = SetAccuracy[-jac2 /. r, per];
  J = SetAccuracy[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[9] - jac2 /. r], per];
  varsz = SetAccuracy[J . M . varst + J . g[varst], per];
  varsy = SetAccuracy[g[varsz], per];
  varsh = SetAccuracy[g[varsy], per];
  a = SetAccuracy[Norm[(varst - varsh), Infinity], per];
  b = SetAccuracy[Norm[f[varsh], Infinity], per];
  varst = varsh;
  Print["k=", NumberForm[k, 20]];
  Print["{h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9}=", NumberForm[varsh, 20]];
  Print["a=", NumberForm[a, 20]];
  Print["b=", NumberForm[b, 20]];
  k = k + 1;];
Print["The number of iterations is:" NumberForm[(k - 1), 2]];
Print["a+b=" NumberForm[a + b, 20]];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the beautiful code. However its not wrorking. The command jac2 is not working and I dont know that 'r' is  when you do -jac2 /. r

Comment: @Learner - Apologies, r is the list of replacement rules, which I forgot to paste. Answer updated to include `r = Table[vars[[n]] -> varst[[n]], {n, Length[vars]}];`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. Encode the general pattern:

```
newF[a_, b_, c_] := b - (100*(a + c - Cos[(-5*a + 5*c)^2]/100))/201
```

Now we just need to figure out how to apply this to subsequences of whatever list you want to pass in. Here's a tricky/fancy way:

```
Partition[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}, 3, 1, {2, -2}, {1, Null, 0}, newF]
```

Note how we used some padding to make sure that a 0 was inserted at the beginning and a 1 at the end.

Here is a way that's probably clearer because the padding is more explicit:

```
BlockMap[Apply[newF], Join[{0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}, {1}], 3, 1]
```

You could put this into a function which could work on either a list as its argument or a sequence. There are probably several other ways you could restructure the list or apply the function to sublists. I haven't looked closely at the rest of your question, but I presume you could do a similar thing with `g`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a vector-valued pure function that returns $\{f_1(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m),f_2(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m), \cdots, f_m(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)\}$ when input $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\}$ (similarly for `g`s) to simplify the first 40+ lines of your code into 4 lines:

```
ClearAll[fvec, gvec]

fvec = # - 100/201 (Prepend[0] @ Most[#] + Append[1] @ Rest[#] - 
       1/100 Cos[(5 # - 5 #2)^2 & @@@ 
          Transpose[{Append[1] @ Rest[#], Prepend[0]@Most[#]}]]) &;

gvec = # - fvec @ # &;
```

**Examples:**

```
vars = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 3];

fvec @ vars  // Column
```

[image]

```
gvec @ vars // Column
```

[image]

```
jacobian = D[gvec @ vars, {vars}];

MatrixForm @ jacobian
```

[image]

```
vars = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 9];

fvec @ vars  // Column
```

[image]

```
vars = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 30];

fvec @ vars  // Column
```

[image]

etc..